# Proxies aren't being applied when using python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm creating a console application that can be used in conjunction with proxies to vote at `strawpoll.me`. Strawpoll has a one vote per IP protocol. I have this code which scrapes proxies from another website and uses them on strawpoll.

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    'https://api.proxyscrape.com/v2/?request=getproxies&protocol=http&timeout=10000&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=all')
proxyfile = [y for y in (x.strip()
                         for x in r.text.splitlines()) if y]
proxy_lines = len(proxyfile)

for line in proxyfile:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    proxies = {'http': f'http://{line}'}
    r = requests.get('https://www.strawpoll.me/45437270')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    data = {'options': '255490396'}
    data['security-token'] = soup.find('input',
                                       attrs={'name': 'security-token'})['value']
    token = soup.find(
        'input', attrs={'id': 'field-authenticity-token'})['value']
    data[token] = ''
    r = requests.post(
        'https://www.strawpoll.me/255630314', data=data, proxies=proxies)
    print(r.text)
    print(proxies)
```

The proxies aren't being applied here for some reason and I keep getting `{"success":"failed"}` from `print(r.text)` But if I use a VPN to change my IP I get a message saying that my vote has been counted. I'm not sure what's wrong here since the docs clearly say to have the proxy saved in a `dict` which I did.